# My floated elements are being pulled too far to the left

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, position

I'm new to CSS, and I've looked for help in the previous forums on this issue. I think I'm doing everything right but my floated elements are being yanked to the left.

[image: The Problem]

Here is my code:

```
div {
display: block;
}

.grid {
width: 660px;
position: relative;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 10px;
clear: left;
}

.home {
text-align: center;
float: left;
width: 33.3333333%;
position: relative;
padding: 25px;
}

.third {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
border-radius: 25px;
}

.third img {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

And my html:

```
<div class="grid">
<article class="home">
  <article class="third">
<img src="" /></article>
</article>
    <article class="home">
  <article class="third">
  <img src="" /></article>
</article>
    <article class="home">
  <article class="third">
  <img src="" /></article>
</article>
</div>
```

Help please!

Comment: what all elements are floated??

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: can u explain little bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet…

[Your original code on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/2oq5cxmm/1/)

The problem come from `padding` in `.home` class. 
I have disabled `padding:25px;` here in `.home` class, because `padding` is added to `width` in CSS:

[The modified version (without padding) on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/2oq5cxmm/5/)

Now it's not "**pulled too far on the left**".
What you can do instead, is to add `margin:25px;` to `.third` class, like this:

[The modified version (with margin) on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/2oq5cxmm/6/)

**EDIT:** A CLEAN REVISITED VERSION:

The HTML code:

```
  <div class="grid">
    <article class="home">
      <div class="third">
        <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/nemo/350/200/1" />
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="home">
      <div class="third">
        <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/6" />
      </div>
    </article>
    <article class="home">
      <div class="third">
        <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/up/350/200/6" />
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
```

**The CSS code:**

```
.grid {
  width: 660px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear: left;
}

.home {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333333%;
}

.third {
  display:table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius:25px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background-color:#eee; //added just for test display
}

.third img {
  border:none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[The result here on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/2oq5cxmm/9/).

[image: Fiddle result in a screenshot]

Images are adaptative, centered vertically and horizontally. 
 
The `.third` class have a light grey background color just for testing and displaying the curved borders and the centered images inside it. 
I have also replaced in html code, the second `<article>` tag by a `<div>` tag, because it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the updated code I think it will work.

```
div {
    display: block;
}
.grid {
    width: 660px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    clear: left;
}
.home {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333333%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.third {
    display:block;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.third img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible correction of your code to you :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8mu2u4t/2/)

I've changed a little the HTML structure like this :

```
<section class="home">
  <article class="third">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" />
  </article>
  <article class="third">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" />
  </article>
  <article class="third">
    <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" />
  </article>
</section>
```

It's better for semantic to have `section` around `article` and not `article` around `article`.

I've simplify the CSS code like this :

```
section.home {
  width: 660px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear: left;
}

article.third {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;    
}

.third img {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

If you use fluid `width` for container, then use fluid `width` for `padding/margin` of article.

In that case, i use fixed `width` of the container and for `padding` values.